# set_axis() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

My code working well on my JupyterLab but I take error when I try to run on coursera's jupyter notebook. It says that "*You are currently looking at version 1.5 of this notebook.*"

```
energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls')
energy = energy.iloc[17:244,2:]
columnnames = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']

energy.set_axis(columnnames, axis=1, inplace=True)

energy = energy.replace('...', np.nan)
energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply']*1000000
dicts = {"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
     "United States of America": "United States",
     "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
     "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong",
     'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)':'Bolivia',
     'Switzerland17':'Switzerland'}
energy["Country"].replace(dicts,inplace=True)
energy=energy.reset_index(drop = True)
energy
```

I took that error:

```
> TypeError: set_axis() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

I think its because of version difference but I couldn't handle it.

Comment: try `energy.set_axis(axis=1, labels=columnnames, inplace=True)`, [present docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) say *Changed in version 0.21.0: The signature is now labels and axis, consistent with the rest of pandas API. Previously, the axis and labels arguments were respectively the first and second positional arguments.* -- so axis was the first parameter in older versions

Comment: @anky now I took `set_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'` error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`df.set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) was changed in version 0.21.0 , as mentioned in docs:

> Changed in version 0.21.0: The signature is now labels and axis, consistent with the rest of pandas API. Previously, the axis and labels arguments were respectively the first and second positional arguments.

When taking a look at the older [version (precisely 0.15.2)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) , the syntax is  `DataFrame.set_axis(axis, labels)` :

So,you can reverse the labels and axis argument and get rid of the `inplace` arg since it is not yet supported for your version , and assign back to the original dataframe instead:

Change:

```
energy.set_axis(columnnames, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

To:

```
energy = energy.set_axis(axis=1, labels=columnnames)
```